# How to iterate list inside a map in ftl?

Tags: java, iterator, freemarker

I have two value objects and i have to write a file using free marker while i am writing it using simply java i am able to iterate the list but don't know how to iterate a map whick consist a variable as well as a list. in my one value object BranchArea i have variable like name and id and a list of Branch. Branch is another value object who as a variable like name etc. i am iterating in java like this

```
List <BranchArea> branchAreaList = new ArrayList<BranchArea>();
Iterator<BranchArea> itrBranchArea = branchAreaList.iterator();
                while (itrBranchArea.hasNext()) {
                    BranchArea branchAreaObj = itrBranchArea.next();
                    LOGGER.error("Branch Area Name is"+branchAreaObj.getBranchAreaName());
                      Iterator<Branch> itrBranch = branchAreaObj.getBranches().iterator();   
                      while(itrBranch.hasNext()){
                          Branch branchObj = itrBranch.next();
                          LOGGER.error("Branch Name is"+branchObj.getBranchName());
                          }
                          }
```

branchAreaList Consist object of BranchArea. For Ftl i convert the branchAreaList  into map

```
HashMap<String, List<BranchArea>> branchAreaMap = new HashMap<String,  List<BranchArea>>();

            branchAreaMap.put("branchAreaList", branchAreaList);
```

**How can i iterate them in Ftl as i iterate it above**

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over keys of your `Map`, and get the elements by this way:

```
  <#list branchAreaMap?keys as key>
        ${key} = ${branchAreaMap[key])}
    </#list>
```